# How to import a photo from device

Tags: android, image

I am working on Kotlin Android Studio Jetpack Compose. I want to browse through images on device and load picture to variable. I know "Image" method, and I want to put the painter dynamically from photos which are on device.

I didn't try much, just browsing web. Looking for a permission to access device files & method to choose program to browse the files. Selected want to display on device.

Comment: I found a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEdC0s9e3NA